# Special Characters (¿) encoding as (?) issue in ADFV2

Tags: ascii, azure-data-factory

I am running copy activity in Azure Data Factory V2. Copying from Oracle to Sql Server.
I have data contains '¿' character ASCII value 191 in source. but when I ran copy activity I am getting '?' in destination ASCII value is 63.

Why adfv2 copy activity replacing special characters?

I have tried with encodingName property of source dataset. with WINDOWS-1252,ISO-8859-1 and UTF-8 but its not working.

How to find this characters falls under which encoding?

Comment: What's the definition of your target table in SQL Server database? I believe that an implicit conversion is taking place on the sink.

Comment: My target table is same as onprem target. Yes implicit conversion.

Comment: What do you mean by "is same as onprem target"? This is crucial. Without sharing schema for the source (Oracle) and target (SQL Server) we can barely help you.